# Get the width of a specific Div then display the following codes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am stuck right now at this scenario.

I have 3 post thumbnails with **different sizes**.

I need to display only one image depending on the size of the screen of the user. I dont like to use css media queries or resize the same image through css because it becomes distorted. Anyway, Is it possible that it can be implemented usign a **PHP IF**?

Something like:

IF blogpost width == 360px
display `<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails2200px', array( 'id'  => "FeatureImage")); ?>`

else if .blogpost width == 300px
display `<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails1280px', array( 'id'  => "FeatureImage")); ?>`

else if .blogpost width == 250px
display `<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails600px', array( 'id'   => "FeatureImage")); ?>`

this is the html structure:

```
<div class="blogpost" id="blogpost">

<a class="post_title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">             
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails2200px', array( 'id'   => "FeatureImage")); ?>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: You need javascript to get browser's dimensions. You could load your content after AJAX sends it the user's viewport size, but this solution smells

Comment: you can send your thumbnail `width` with a `GET` parameter and use it.

Comment: Something else to consider will be if the resolution changes the image will not change with it (resizing of the browser)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this
(please note if you have pretty permalink enable make sure you use this line instead just change the first & to ?

document.location=\"$url?r=1&width=\"+screen.width+\"&Height=\"+screen.height)

```
<?php     
// Get the current page
 $url =  get_permalink($post->ID);
if(!isset($_GET['r']))     
{     
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">     
<!--      
document.location=\"$url&r=1&width=\"+screen.width+\"&Height=\"+screen.height;     
 //-->     
</script>";     
 }     
else {         

// Code to be displayed if resolutoin is detected     
 if(isset($_GET['width']) && isset($_GET['Height'])) {     
           // Resolution  detected     
           $blogpost_width =  $_GET['width'];

 }     
 else {     
           // Resolution not detected     
 }     
}     

?>
```